# How to call storyboard animation backwards?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I have a storyboard animation which i want to play backwards on a certain condition

storyboard1.autoreverse = true;

is not what i want

its like i want to change the to & from fields

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" Completed="Storyboard1_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this in the framework, however, it is easy to do yourself:

```
private void Reverse(Storyboard sb)
{
  DoubleAnimation anim = sb.Children.OfType<DoubleAnimation>().Single();
  object temp = anim.From;
  anim.From = anim.To;
  anim.To = Temp;
}
```

Which you could use as follows:

```
Reverse(this.Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard);
```

Comment: I have some doubts about this solution because you would need to reposition/reverse the keyframes as well.

Comment: @ColinE: could you be a bit more specific, seeing the code that i posted suppose i want to make "imageBack1" to "image1" and vice-versa.

Comment: @Emo good point. However, my statement that "there is no support for this in the framework" is the important point in my answer. You have to do this yourself by editing the StoryBoard.

Answer (score 0):

I've to manually reverse a storyboard:

```
    // does not work.
    public static Storyboard Reverse(Storyboard storyboard)
    {
        Storyboard newStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        newStoryboard.SpeedRatio = storyboard.SpeedRatio;
        foreach (var unknownChild in storyboard.Children)
        {
            if (unknownChild is DoubleAnimation)
            {
                DoubleAnimation child = unknownChild as DoubleAnimation;
                DoubleAnimation newChild = new DoubleAnimation()
                {
                    Duration = child.Duration,
                    // AutoReverse, BeginTime, FillBehaviour, RepeatBehaviour, SpeedRatio?
                    From = child.To,
                    To = child.From,
                    EasingFunction = child.EasingFunction
                };
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newChild, Storyboard.GetTargetProperty(child));
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(newChild, Storyboard.GetTargetName(child));
                newStoryboard.Children.Add(newChild);
            }
            else if (unknownChild is ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames)
            {
                ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames child = unknownChild as ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames;
                var newChild = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
                {
                    Duration = (child as Timeline).Duration,
                };
                foreach (ObjectKeyFrame keyFrame in child.KeyFrames)
                {
                    var newKeyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame() {
                        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(child.Duration.TimeSpan - keyFrame.KeyTime.TimeSpan),
                        Value = keyFrame.Value
                    };
                    newChild.KeyFrames.Add(newKeyFrame);
                }
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(newChild, Storyboard.GetTargetName(child));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newChild, Storyboard.GetTargetProperty(child));
                newStoryboard.Children.Add(newChild);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("type " + unknownChild + " not supported");
            }
        }
        return newStoryboard;
    }
```

However, the main problem seems to be that even though i transfer the TargetName and TargetProperty values, the new storyboard cannot find the correct elements.

Unfortunately I do not know how the Storyboard class figures out it's location in the Xaml Tree / it's Resources parent :/